# Using Pseudovariables in a c# project

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to use $tid [pseudovariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables) in a c# project but keep getting error

> error CS0103: The name '$tid' does not exist in the current context

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scroll down that documentation page. In C#, the only supported pseudovariables are `$exception` and `$user`.